# How to check a char is EOF or \n

Tags: c, string, char

I would like to count how many sentences in the paragraph, and the sentence is defined as

1. a sentence ends in `.` followed by two spaces, such as `"a.  "`
2. a sentence ends in `.` followed by a newline (`'\n'`), such as `"a.\n"`
3. a sentence ends in `.` at end of file, such as `"a."` followed by `EOF`.

My approach is as follows

I tried to use `strncmp(&s, "\n", 1) == 0` and `strncmp(&s, "\0", 1) == 0` to check the `\n` and `EOF`.

However, it failed to check the `\n` and `EOF`

How to check if a character is `EOF` or `\n` in the C language?

```
int main() {
    char s;
    int count = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &s) != EOF) {
        if (strncmp(&s, ".", 1) == 0) {
            scanf("%c", &s);
            if (strncmp(&s, "\n", 1) == 0) {
                count++;
            } else
            if (strncmp(&s, "\0", 1) == 0) {
                count++;
                printf("%d", count);
                return 0;
            } else
            if (strncmp(&s, " ", 1) == 0) {
                scanf("%c", &s);
                if (strncmp(&s, " ", 1) == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of e.g. `strncmp(&s,".",1)==0`, why not simply `y == '.'`?

Comment: And perhaps what you really need is [the `getchar` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)? But please note that it returns an **`int`**, which is important for the comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: So a `.` followed by a single space is not a sentence!?

Comment: `EOF` is incompatible with `char`. In "regular" computers `char` can be set to any of `256` different values. `EOF` is **NOT** any of those values. `EOF` **IS NOT** a character, `EOF` is a signal... much like "how many ioghurts are in your fridge?" cannot accept the answer "Wrong question ... I sold my fridge" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code fails for at least these reasons:

- `scanf("%c", &s);` lacks a return value check and so may miss a return value of `EOF`.
- After `if (strncmp(&s, ".", 1) == 0) {` is true, if the next character read is `'.'`, code does not reset to properly check for the candidate end sequences.

---

**Weak coding**

`strncmp(&s, ".", 1) == 0` is a convoluted way to perform `s == '.'`.

**Line count may exceed `INT_MAX`**

Consider wider types.

**Consider `getchar()`**

Instead of `scanf("%c", &s)`, use `int ch = getchar()`.  `ch` will typically contain 1 of 256 characters: 0-255 or the negative value `EOF`.  Then testing for `EOF` is as simple as `ch == EOF`.

**Append a `'\n'`**

Good practice to end output with a `'\n'`.

---

Instead avoid complex code and try to code as close to the requirements as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long count = 0;
  int prior[2] = {EOF, EOF};  // 2 prior characters.

  for (;;) {
    int ch = getchar();

    // sentence ends in . followed by two spaces, such as "a.  "
    if (prior[1] == '.' && prior[0] == ' ' && ch == ' ') {
      count++;
    }

    // sentence ends in . followed by a newline ('\n'), such as "a.\n"
    else if (prior[0] == '.' && ch == '\n') {
      count++;
    }

    // sentence ends in . at end of file, such as "a." followed by EOF.
    else if (ch == EOF) {
      if (prior[0] == '.') {
        count++;
      }
      break;
    }

    prior[1] = prior[0];
    prior[0] = ch;
  }

  printf("%llu\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Perhaps OP would also like to add an A-Z,a-z detection.  Easy enough to do with a larger `prior[]`, `<ctype.h>`.  Example change for one test:

```
if (isalpha(prior[2]) && prior[1] == '.' && prior[0] == ' ' && ch == ' ') {
  count++;
}
```

Comment: @ident Tip: Include coding requirements, as a comment, near the code that does it.  It is useful for later review.

Answer (score 3):

- `EOF` is of type `int` so you cannot reliably check if a `char` is `EOF` since the value may be out of bounds.
- `char` has implementation-defined signedness and `EOF` is often defined as a negative number, so it is quite possible that a `char` can never hold `EOF` for that reason alone. [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)
- This is why functions like `getchar` do not actually return a `char`, but an `int`. Yes, that's some seriously rotten API, but the functions have been like that since the early 1970s.

Comment: The general best practice is to avoid `stdio.h` for any other purpose than quick & dirty debugging and the like. Beginners shouldn't waste significant time on learning about brain-damaged APIs to ancient console I/O functions, when they could better spent that time learning about actual programming.

Comment: "best practice is to avoid stdio.h" --> Without `stdio.h`, how do you recommend a portable program read a file or print to `stdout`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The same way as you design a portable-anything: write a HAL. It's not rocket science to write a thin HAL on top of some API functions. You'll need one anyway because stdio.h doesn't have a clue about file attributes, file searching, directories and so on. And well, not _all_ of stdio.h is extremely poorly designed, just around 99% of it. `puts` is a nice little function.

Comment: In the unlikely event that anyone can name any other library for any programming language which has caused anywhere near as much physical and/or monetary damage to mankind than stdio.h, I would be interested to hear about it though. windows.h and unistd.h are likely candidates - they are remarkably poorly designed too. But they are still nowhere near stdio.h.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you read characters using `scanf("%c", &s)` you can't check for EOF. When reading characters one-by-one it's better to use `getchar`. The `getchar` function returns an `int` which allow you to check for EOF.
2. For comparing characters you don't want `strncmp`. Characters can be compared directly using `==`.

To make the logic simple I'll suggest using a state variable, i.e. to remember what you have previously read. For instance:

```
#define DOT           0  // Last character was '.'
#define DOT_SPACE     1  // Last two characters was '. '
#define NO_MORE_INPUT 2  // Last character was EOF
#define OTHER         3  // Other (i.e. at start or middle of a sentence)
```

When you have read a character you use the current state and the character value to determine 1) was this end-of-sentence and 2) what is the new state.

So for each state you need something like:

```
      if (c == '.')
      {
        ++count; ??
        state = ??
      }
      else if (c == ' ')
      {
        ++count; ??
        state = ??
      }
      else if (c == '\n')
      {
        ++count; ??
        state = ??
      }
      else if (c == EOF)
      {
        ++count; ??
        state = ??
      }
      else
      {
        ++count; ??
        state = ??
      }
```

The example code below uses more lines than needed but that's not important. The important thing is to understand the principle:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DOT           0
#define DOT_SPACE     1
#define NO_MORE_INPUT 2
#define OTHER         3

int main(void) {
  int state = OTHER;
  int c;
  int count=0;
  while(state != NO_MORE_INPUT)
  {
    c = getchar();
    switch(state)
    {
      case OTHER:
          if (c == '.')
          {
            state = DOT;
          }
          else if (c == ' ')
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          else if (c == '\n')
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          else if (c == EOF)
          {
            state = NO_MORE_INPUT;
          }
          else
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          break;

      case DOT:
          if (c == '.')
          {
            state = DOT;
          }
          else if (c == ' ')
          {
            state = DOT_SPACE;
          }
          else if (c == '\n')
          {
            ++count;
            state = OTHER;
          }
          else if (c == EOF)
          {
            ++count;
            state = NO_MORE_INPUT;
          }
          else
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          break;

      case DOT_SPACE:
          if (c == '.')
          {
            state = DOT;
          }
          else if (c == ' ')
          {
            ++count;
            state = OTHER;
          }
          else if (c == '\n')
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          else if (c == EOF)
          {
            state = NO_MORE_INPUT;
          }
          else
          {
            state = OTHER;
          }
          break;

      default:
          // Error
          exit(1);
    }
  }

  printf("%d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "When you read characters using `scanf("%c", &s)`, you can't check for EOF" — that's not entirely accurate, though you can't look at `s` after the call to detect EOF.  The correct way to work is `if (scanf("%s", &s) != 1) { …EOF or read error… }`.  Note that the return value should be checked against the expected value — 1 successful character read — rather than looking for EOF.  With `%c` alone in the format string, it actually wouldn't matter, but in general, `scanf()` can return positive N (for the number of successful, assigned conversions), or 0 (no successful conversions) or EOF (error).

Comment: Thank you. It enlightens me many different way.